# Replacing notebook screen with new one

Tags: laptop, display

I have dell 3550 and it's screen is broken.

I also have another laptop Asus N56VZ. Can I put ASUS N56VZ'S screen to Dell 3550?

Both screen resolutions are 1920x1080
Both are LED screens
Both are with 30 pin connector
Both mounting points are identical

Is there anything else?

Comment: If everything matches up, as you describe it does, then it probably should work.

Comment: I want to sure that i'm not missing anything that is internal. thanks for comment.